# ObjectMapper cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have troubles getting JSON to work. `ObjectMapper` cannot be resolved. Library is imported correctly.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import net.sf.json.JSONException;
import net.sf.json.util.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.*;

public class Json {
    private static final String jsonFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Juergen\\Desktop\\filesForExamples\\mapExample.json";

    public static void objectToJSON(HashMap<String, Mat> map) {
        //Map<String, Object> mapObject = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(new File(jsonFilePath), map);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Importing `ObjectMapper` would be a really good idea.

Comment: yeah, but shouldnt eclipse give me the proposal?

Comment: If Eclipse has something like a "quick fix", then it would could suggest an import. But I don't know if it has such a feature. But anyway, this problem is the missing import, so you could delete this question, because it won't help future readers and asking, why Eclipse doesn't suggest an import before noting the error, is quite off-topic :P.

Comment: This is maybe something what you're looking for: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_Quick_Fix%3F

Comment: i found out that i need to import the jackson package additionally. i downloaded it. But how do i get the full path to know for a correct package import?

Comment: Depends on your version. Check the JavaDoc of your version or use Ctrl+Space for auto completion. Eclipse should then show available classes for import.

Comment: jar file without java doc, auto completion not helping

Comment: You don't need the JavaDoc in the jar, since it should be available on the internet :P.

Comment: what has any javadoc to do with the downloaded package name?sorry i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: It contains the full qualified name.

Comment: if u want to auto import needed objects in eclipse, use the shortcut ctrl + shift + o..

Comment: if u just downloaded Jackson as jar file, dont forget to add it to your buildpath

Comment: added, still not found the mapper

Comment: did u refreshed your project ? (if you just copied the jar file in a folder like /lib inside your project, eclipse wont recognize, until you refresh) and maybe should clean and recompile..

Comment: refreshed!But the jackson packages doesn't contain "databind"

Comment: and make sure, that you have the jar file "..jackson-databind..", for using ObjectMapper ..

Comment: yeah there are several packages of jackson, for using ObjectMapper u need to get jackson-databind. So you have for jackson atleast 2 jar files.. jackson-core and jackson-databind

Comment: Lunatikz you re right, thanks

Comment: it's a shame that for serialization of generics you need 3 packages

Comment: u r welcome :) If you like, u can upvote my comment ;)

Answer (score 14):

```
If you are using **maven** project then add the following in the `POM.xml`

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
    
But if you are using a **simple java** project then you need to add the following jars in your class path:
    
    jackson-core-2.1.X,
    jackson-databind-2.1.X
```

Answer (score 9):

Add `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;` to your project.